# How would I remove an index from ArrayList after a return statement?

Tags: java

I am working on an class lab and ran into some trouble. We have been asked to write a method with the following instructions:

"Dog getRandomDog() - randomly selects a dog, returns it, and removes
it from the kennel. Returns null if there are no dogs."

This is the method that I wrote (which doesn't work):

```
public Dog getRandomDog(){
    if(dogs.size() >= 0){
        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.nextInt(dogs.size());
        return dogs.get(index);
        dogs.remove(index);
   }
    else {
    return null;
   }
}
```

I do understand that you cant have an executable statement after a return, but then how the heck to do you around this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I come from an old school of thought *One entry, one exit*

```
public Dog getRandomDog(){
    Dog dog = null;
    if(dogs.size() >= 0){
        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.nextInt(dogs.size());
        dog = dogs.remove(index);
    }
    return dog;
}
```

This basically means that you allow one point of entry for your method (a little mute in Java) and one exit (or one `return`).  This makes the method easier to understand as you don't need to worry about the method exiting half way through.  Really a pain when the method can run several screens lengths...

Answer (score 1):

After `return` the code will not run

```
return dogs.get(index);
dogs.remove(index);  // <--- This will not execute after return
```

Try to `return` the result of `remove`:

```
return dogs.remove(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

dogs.remove(index) itself will remove the Dog object at index and return it as well.

```
return dogs.remove(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove before the return statement

```
 public Dog getRandomDog(){
    Dog d = null;
    if(dogs.size() >= 0){
        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.nextInt(dogs.size());
        d = dogs.remove(index);
    }
    return d;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the collection that dogs is a type of returns the object itself on calling remove, you can simply do:

int index = random.nextInt(dogs.size());
        return dogs.remove(index);

Answer (score 0):

The most compact version would be:

```
Dog d = dogs.remove(getRandomDog());  

public Dog getRandomDog()  {  
    return dogs.size() > 0 ?  dogs.get((int)(Math.random()*dogs.size())) : null;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work, apart from most of the answers above

```
public Dog getRandomDog(){
if(!dogs.isEmpty()){
    Random random = new Random();
    int index = random.nextInt(dogs.size());
    try{
    return dogs.get(index);
    }finally{
    dogs.remove(index);
   }
}
 else {
  return null;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I voted up @MadProgrammer.

```java
public Dog getRandomDog() {
    return dogs.isEmpty() ?
        null : dogs.remove(new Random().nextInt(dogs.size()));
}
```